# Can no longer deploy from with AWS Toolkit for VS 2019

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, web-deployment

I was able to deploy from Visual Studio to my AWS Elastic Beanstalk instance as of April 2021.  Now, when I tried yesterday and today, I am getting errors when trying to upload the deployment zip file to S3.  Is there a solution for this on the AWS side?  Not sure what the problem is here.   Notice the percent numbers sometimes go backwards...?   Thanks!

If AWS is down, where is the deployment zip file stored so I can manually upload to EB?

---

Output Log from VS:

> ..preparing up aws deployment manifest file ..zipping publishing
> directory ..deployment package created successfully... ...starting
> redeployment to AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment 'CrumsWeb-UAT1'
> ....uploading application deployment package to Amazon S3
> ......uploaded 0% of application deployment package ......uploaded 1%
> of application deployment package ......uploaded 2% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 3% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 4% of application deployment package ......uploaded 5%
> of application deployment package ......uploaded 6% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 7% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 8% of application deployment package ......uploaded 9%
> of application deployment package ......uploaded 10% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 11% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 12% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 13% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 14% of application deployment package ......uploaded 15% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 16% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 17% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 18% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 19% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 20% of application deployment package ......uploaded 21% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 22% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 23% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 24% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 11% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 12% of application deployment package ......uploaded 13% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 14% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 13% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 14% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 15% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 16% of application deployment package ......uploaded 17% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 18% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 19% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 20% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 21% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 22% of application deployment package ......uploaded 23% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 24% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 25% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 26% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 27% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 28% of application deployment package ......uploaded 15% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 16% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 17% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 18% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 19% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 20% of application deployment package ......uploaded 21% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 22% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 23% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 24% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 25% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 26% of application deployment package ......uploaded 27% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 28% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 29% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 30% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 17% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 18% of application deployment package ......uploaded 19% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 20% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 21% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 22% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 23% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 24% of application deployment package ......uploaded 25% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 26% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 27% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 28% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 29% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 30% of application deployment package ......uploaded 31% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 32% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 33% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 34% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 35% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 36% of application deployment package ......uploaded 37% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 38% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 39% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 26% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 27% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 28% of application deployment package ......uploaded 29% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 30% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 31% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 32% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 33% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 34% of application deployment package ......uploaded 35% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 36% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 37% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 24% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 25% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 26% of application deployment package ......uploaded 27% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 28% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 29% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 30% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 31% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 32% of application deployment package ......uploaded 33% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 34% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 35% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 36% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 37% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 38% of application deployment package ......uploaded 39% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 40% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 41% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 42% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 30% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 31% of application deployment package ......uploaded 32% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 33% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 34% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 35% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 36% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 37% of application deployment package ......uploaded 38% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 39% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 40% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 41% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 42% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 43% of application deployment package ......uploaded 44% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 45% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 46% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 47% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 34% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 35% of application deployment package ......uploaded 36% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 37% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 38% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 39% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 40% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 28% of application deployment package ......uploaded 29% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 30% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 31% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 32% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 33% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 34% of application deployment package ......uploaded 35% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 36% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 37% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 38% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 39% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 35% of application deployment package ......uploaded 22% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 23% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 24% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 25% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 26% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 27% of application deployment package ......uploaded 28% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 18% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 19% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 20% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 21% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 22% of application deployment package ......uploaded 23% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 24% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 25% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 26% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 27% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 28% of application deployment package ......uploaded 29% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 30% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 31% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 18% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 19% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 20% of application deployment package ......uploaded 21% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 22% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 23% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 24% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 25% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 26% of application deployment package ......uploaded 27% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 28% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 29% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 30% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 31% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 32% of application deployment package ......uploaded 33% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 20% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 21% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 22% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 23% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 24% of application deployment package ......uploaded 25% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 26% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 27% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 28% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 29% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 30% of application deployment package ......uploaded 31% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 32% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 33% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 34% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 35% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 36% of application deployment package ......uploaded 24% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 25% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 26% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 27% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 28% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 29% of application deployment package ......uploaded 30% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 31% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 32% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 33% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 34% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 35% of application deployment package ......uploaded 25% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 23% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 24% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 25% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 26% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 27% of application deployment package ......uploaded 28% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 29% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 30% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 31% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 32% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 33% of application deployment package ......uploaded 34% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 35% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 36% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 23% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 24% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 25% of application deployment package ......uploaded 26% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 27% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 28% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 29% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 30% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 31% of application deployment package ......uploaded 32% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 33% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 34% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 35% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 36% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 37% of application deployment package ......uploaded 38% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 26% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 14% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 15% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 16% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 17% of application deployment package ......uploaded 18% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 19% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 20% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 21% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 22% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 23% of application deployment package ......uploaded 24% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 25% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 26% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 27% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 28% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 29% of application deployment package ......uploaded 30% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 31% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 32% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 33% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 34% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 35% of application deployment package ......uploaded 36% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 37% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 38% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 39% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 40% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 28% of application deployment package ......uploaded 29% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 16% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 17% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 18% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 19% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 10% of application deployment package ......uploaded 11% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 12% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 13% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 14% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 15% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 16% of application deployment package ......uploaded 17% of
> application deployment package ......uploaded 18% of application
> deployment package ......uploaded 19% of application deployment
> package ......uploaded 20% of application deployment package
> ......uploaded 21% of application deployment package ......uploaded
> 22% of application deployment package ......uploaded 23% of
> application deployment package Publish to AWS Elastic Beanstalk failed
> with exception: A WebException with status ReceiveFailure was thrown.,
> Inner Exception Message: The underlying connection was closed: An
> unexpected error occurred on a receive. Error publishing application:
> Unhandled error during deployment

Answer (score 0):

It ended up being my internet service was slow and the uploads were timing out.  My ISP fixed some hardware and all is good now.

I would still like to know where the zip file that gets uploaded is stored.